# TextView Disappears after Screen Rotation

Tags: java, android, textview, lifecycle

I am new to savedInstanceState.  There are some great resources out there, and I have nearly figured it all out.  However, my TextView updates like I want it to, but it disappears.  I want it to remain there when I rotate the device instead of having to click a button to bring it back.  Any idea on where I am going wrong?  Thanks!

TextView cashView is where I want to see int cash.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
      // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
      // killed and restarted.
      savedInstanceState.putInt("cash", cash);
      savedInstanceState.putInt("anteBet", anteBet);
      savedInstanceState.putInt("playBet", playBet);
      savedInstanceState.putInt("pairPlusBet", pairPlusBet);
      savedInstanceState.putString("cashView", cashView.toString());
      // etc.
    }

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  cash = savedInstanceState.getInt("cash");
  anteBet = savedInstanceState.getInt("anteBet");
  playBet = savedInstanceState.getInt("playBet");
  pairPlusBet = savedInstanceState.getInt("pairPlusBet");
  cashView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(cashView.toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha...after an hour of fiddling with it, i figured it out as soon as I finished asking the question. Thanks for your time though!

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putInt("cash", cash);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("anteBet", anteBet);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("playBet", playBet);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("pairPlusBet", pairPlusBet);
  savedInstanceState.putString("cashView", cashView.getText().toString());
  // etc.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  cash = savedInstanceState.getInt("cash");
  anteBet = savedInstanceState.getInt("anteBet");
  playBet = savedInstanceState.getInt("playBet");
  pairPlusBet = savedInstanceState.getInt("pairPlusBet");
  cashView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("cashView"));
}
```

I changed 
      savedInstanceState.putString("cashView", cashView.toString());
to 
      savedInstanceState.putString("cashView", cashView.getText().toString());

and i changed 
  cashView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(cashView.toString()));
to 
  cashView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("cashView"));

Not sure which one fixed it, but its fixed.  Thanks anyways!